# Mariadb driver Aurora IAM credentialType Access denied for user (using password: YES)

Tags: mariadb, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, hikaricp

We use MariaDB driver 2.7.3 & Hikari Datasource in the Java 11 application to connect to the AWS Aurora database. Intermittently we are getting **"Access denied to user"
(using password: YES)** error in the error log files. The following is the JDBC URL used in the application.

```
jdbc:mariadb:aurora://<DB writer cluster endpoint>:port,<DB reader cluster endpoint>:port/<DB name>?credentialType=AWS-IAM&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true&serverSslCert=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&autoReconnect=true&fastConnect=true&tcpNoDelay=true&socketTimeout=0
```

credentialType=AWS-IAM will use the RDS token as the password. From the error message, it looks like the expired token is used to get a database connection by the MariaDB driver. Is this a bug in the MariaDB driver? Let us know if there is anything else we need to do from an application end? These are the properties set from the application.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=60
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=1000
spring.datasource.hikari.login-timeout=2000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=180000
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cachePrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSize=1000
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useServerPrepStmts=true
```